# Meteor return a new dom element form an helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-helper

I have a javascript string with html code and I want to add it to the DOM. I'm now doing this:
HTML file:

```
 {{bodyText}}
```

JS file:

```
Template.post.bodyText = function(){
    var p = document.createElement("p")
    p.append(this.body)
    return p
}
```

But I keep getting a giant error on console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `$(p).append(this.body)`?

Comment: Yup. That way I get the strings all wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a string with html content like this: "<h2>Hello</2> World". And I want to add this to a paragraph in html. Simple as that.

Comment: You can use `{{{bodyText}}}` in html and `return "<p>"+this.body+"</p>";` in the helper function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how a templating system should be used. Template helpers should return data not markup.

template:

```
<template name="post">
    <body>
        <p>
           {{bodyText}}
        </p>
    </body>
</template>
```

Template helper:

```
Template.post.bodyText = function(){
   return 'Yourtext';
}
```